# MySQL won't allow Java Program to insert using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, client-server

I have a Java Server that connects to a MySQL database using JDBC.  I have created a user for the server to use and granted it all permissions on the database.  MySQL allows Select commands from the server. However, any updates or inserts fail.  I have logged in to MySQL from the terminal using the same user as the server and I am allowed to insert.  I'm not sure what's going on.

Something else to note is that if I run the server locally with a local instance of MySQL, everything works just fine.  However, this problem occurs on an Amazon EC2 server.

Many thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you've solved your problem. Just FYI, if you want MySQL to be case-insensitive on Unix, you can add the following line to your my.cnf file:

> lower_case_table_names = 1

On Windows and Mac, MySQL is case-insensitive by default. But on Unix, it's case-sensitive by default. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html for more info on that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that MySQL cares about the case of table names...